# Set data-theme programatically on textbox in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to set the "data-theme" of a textbox in Jquery mobile?

```
$("#txtEmail").attr("data-theme", "b");
```

...doesn't work.

I like to use this to to display invalid form items in form validation.

Comment: For anybody else getting to this answer from google: the answers below work for this simple case, but won't work for other widgets than the textbox. From what I can tell, when you apply a data-theme, that data-theme also gets applied to nested jquery mobile widgets.  All of these nested widgets will also need to have their data-theme attribute and their classes updated.  To complicate things further, it looks like some widgets apply parent data-theme's to particular nested widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually remove the earlier theme class and add the new theme class after changing the theme.

```
$("#txtEmail").removeClass("ui-body-c").addClass("ui-body-b");
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/vppvG/

Comment: Thanks for the demo! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To conform to jquerymobile standards I would use:

> $("#txtEmail").attr('data-theme','b').trigger('refresh');