# How to change the init options of the listview for every instance of dynamically created listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

Say i have a listview string

```
 var html = "";
html += "<ol id=list2>"+
.... + 
"</ol>"
```

Based on user input i have to vary the theme and few other properties of the listview that i create from the above string.

I tried the below but the listview was not refreshing.

```
$("#home div:jqmData(role=content)").append (html);
$("#list2").listview();
```

- $("#list2").attr('data-theme', 'e');
     $("#list2").listview('refresh');
- $("#list2").jqmData("theme", "e")
     $("#list2").listview('refresh');

But the theme was not updating. Similarly i have to update few other properties of the listview like `inset`, `splitIcon`. Please let me know how to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

To change the theme programmatically, changing the `data-theme` attribute is not enough, you also have to remove the classes added by the old theme and add the new ones by hand. Here you have a couple of links that point this out:

[Set data-theme programatically on textbox in Jquery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923255/set-data-theme-programatically-on-textbox-in-jquery-mobile)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-refresh-the-theme-of-a-button

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can not be done with listview refresh, you will need to do this to achieve a theme change:

```
var newTheme = 'b';

$.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn, .ui-li, .ui-listview').removeClass('ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-up-d ui-btn-up-e ui-btn-hover-a ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-hover-d ui-btn-hover-e').addClass('ui-btn-up-' + newTheme ).attr('data-theme', newTheme );
$.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-header, .ui-footer').removeClass('ui-bar-a ui-bar-b ui-bar-c ui-bar-d ui-bar-e').addClass('ui-bar-' + newTheme ).attr('data-theme', newTheme );
$.mobile.activePage.removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e').addClass('ui-body-' + newTheme ).attr('data-theme', newTheme );
```

Here's my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/. You should comment above code to see a difference.